# Ошибка при установке PyAudio

Tags: python, python-3.x

Извините за такой вопрос, но я не понимаю что нужно делать в этой ситуации.

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\sergey\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sergey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p4v8aqhb\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sergey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p4v8aqhb\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-jv38zad_'
       cwd: C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p4v8aqhb\pyaudio\
  Complete output (15 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\sergey\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\sergey\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory,
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
  Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for PyAudio which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\sergey\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sergey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p4v8aqhb\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sergey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p4v8aqhb\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ycu9n1z_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\sergey\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p4v8aqhb\pyaudio\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\sergey\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\sergey\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: portaudio.h: No such file or directory,
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\sergey\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sergey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p4v8aqhb\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sergey\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p4v8aqhb\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ycu9n1z_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\sergey\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас установлен Python 3.8, а под него нет готовых бинарников [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/). Компиляция из исходников - задача нетривиальная, поэтому советую поставить Python версии 3.6. Под ним установка должна пройти без проблем, т.к. все необходимые модули уже включены в официальный дистрибутив.